# Leave calculation mistake odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-10

Hi i want to calculate half day leave for an employee. when applying for leave, the duration is set as `1/05/2018 18:30 -1/05/2018 23:30`. ie `1.00pm to 6.00pm` (ist).the day's calculation shows as 0.5 days. Working hour is scheduled as 9.00-18.00. But when generating payslip for the same employee total working days is shown as 31 days and working hours as 279. Odoo does not calculate the half day leave. how can i fix this? i have a doubt about specifying the time in duration while applying for leave. is it should be converted to utc? 
[image]

[image]